# Connecting to and making transaction (CRUD) to attached SQL DB on the server by C# for multi-user WinForm App

Tags: c#, linq, client-server

I'm using LINQ technology (`DataContext`) with a repository design pattern to code a Winforms application. I'm new to programing so I watched some tutorial movies and my app is almost finished.

This is puzzling me that any of those movies don’t say a single word about multiuser (client-server) program with LINQ technology (because my app has more than a thousand users and I have to handle them via intranet).

My question is: just adjusting connection string in `app.config` (like below) do the chores?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.DBConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=ServerIP;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Does it mean that installing the app on all user’s system result in connecting all of them to the server and enabling do transaction with the attached database (which it’s connection string has entered in the `app.config`) on the server?

Would you please guide me how to know more about this topic?

Comment: You need one server where the database is available and it should be connectable from the machine where you install the application. That's how it works. And it takes care of multi user scenarios too.

Comment: So, if I got it wright, you mean there is no need to do socket and port programming and LING do all we need, am I wright?

Comment: And, would you please tell me if my connection string has been set correctly? I doubt specially about where and how to locate "ServerIP".

Comment: Let me ask one more question, can we manipulate the port in which Visual Studio (LINQ) transfer data to SQL? (Some security policies oblige me to use a special port No)

Comment: ServerIP is the IP of the sql server.

Comment: I'm not sure which one is true, IP of the SQL server or the IP of the SERVER!